# How do you build page within a folder in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to have my URL as /social/fb/, i've tried looking online and documentation but can't find the answer to this simple question for the life of me.

My folder structure is:
Pages
-social
--fb

I have a social.vue file in pages which works fine as [www.example.com/social](http://www.example.com/social) but can't get [www.example.com/social/fb](http://www.example.com/social/fb). Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create social folder inside pages, then create fb.vue inside social folder.
This should work

Answer (score 0):

I normally load the `layout.vue` from the router and treat everything else as a child which is passed though as a router-view, this then saves having an `index.vue` for each parent.

But you would always want to make a directory to contain the *social* pages. Then would be a case of simply adding to the router.js file.

**layouts/template.vue**

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'layout-template'
}
</script>
```

**router.js**

```
  ...
  /*
   * Social
   */
  {
    path: '/social',
    component: () => import('./layout/template.vue'),
    props: true,
    // rendered inside <router-view>
    children: [{
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('./pages/social/index.vue')
    }, {
      path: 'fb',
      component: () => import('./pages/social/fb.vue')
    }, {
      path: 'twitter',
      component: () => import('./pages/social/twitter.vue')
    },
    // or do something more dynamic
    {
      path: ':network', // accessible in component though `$route.params.network`
      props: true, // makes accessible though `props: ['network']` 
      component: () => import('./pages/social/network.vue')
    }]
  },
  ...
```

**./pages/social/index.vue** - could show something `/social` homepage or change route to `import('./pages/not-found.vue')` instead.

**./pages/social/network.vue**

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "page-social-network",
  props: {
    network: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  created() {
    // or through
    this.$route.params.network
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped></style>
```

See: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html#boolean-mode

Otherwise is just standard vue pages